# How to optimize the Image GridView in Android?

Tags: java, android, gridview

Scroll is not smooth when loading the grid view. it takes some time to scroll .
So how can i optimize the gridview so i can put more images on that grid view. please suggest me some ways to optimize the Grid view.

1. Main Xml file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
   <GridView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="180dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:id="@+id/imggrid">
   </GridView>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Main Activity

   ```
   package com.blogspot.techyy360.ukook_splash;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.image_grid);
   GridView gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.imggrid);
   gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked on Recipie "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
   });
       }
     }
   ```
3. CustomAdapter for image grid view

   ```
   package com.blogspot.techyy360.ukook_splash;


       import android.content.Context;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
      import android.widget.GridView;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.ProgressBar;
      import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
     private Context mcontext;
   @Override
    public int getCount() {
   return img.length;
      }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
   return img[position];
   }

    @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
    }
    public CustomAdapter(Context c){
     mcontext=c;
      }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ImageView imgview;
        if(convertView==null){
       imgview=new ImageView(mcontext);
       imgview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(525, 400));
       imgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
       imgview.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

   }else{
       imgview=(ImageView) convertView;
   }
   imgview.setImageResource(img[position]);
   return imgview;
         }
        public Integer[] img={
       R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
       R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image3,
       R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
       R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
       R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image1,
       R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1,
       R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1,
       R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image1
      };
     }
   ```

Comment: How can we suggest optimization without seeing the code? In two words: use RecyclerView

Comment: ok i am sending you to code

Comment: Edit and add the code, use a holder, don't always inflate the view as it is being recycled so you can use the convert view, also, consider using Glide library to load images, I will add my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my full CustomAdapter code, using glide library. it is fast and smooth, however, consider changing the `diskCacheStartegy` you are using when loading images, depending on your needs.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

public class CustomAdapter3 extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    public static int[] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomAdapter3(Context con, int[] prgmImages) {
        context = con;
        imageId = prgmImages;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageId.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list3, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(imageId[position])
                .dontAnimate()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
                .into(holder.img);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmitKumawat I gave you a full code of an adapter, using holder and glide, just implement it to your code... I am not your teacher.